# Why aren't these statements both true?

Tags: logic, quantifiers

Let $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$

**Statement 1:** For all $x$ there exists $y$ such that $x\lt y$

**Statement 2:** There exists $x$ such that for all $y$ we have $x\lt y$

Statement 1 is *true* (choose $y=x+1$), but Statement 2 is *false*, but can't we just make $x=y-1$? I found the $x$ such that for any $y$ we choose, $x$ is less than it, and that solution is $x=y-1$. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with statement $2$ is that this $x$ needs to work *for each and every single possible $y$.*

In the first statement, we have "there exists $y$" after stating what $x$ is; the $y$ in that scenario thus can depend on $x$.

In the second statement, however, we don't have such a benefit: "there exists $x$" comes first. Whatever $x$ would work needs to satisfy $x<y$ for $y=1$, for $y=100$, for $y=-10^{10^{10}}$, and so on and so forth: it needs to work for every possible number.

But that would mean that $x<y$ for every real number $y$ ... which can't be satisfied by any real number.

Comment: Your "$y$ can depend on $x$" point made me realize the for statement 2, $y$ could easily be equal to $x-1$ making $x\lt y$ impossible